# MySQL order by specific JSON value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So there is one specific DataTable I am working with which handles large amounts of data, so all the logic is in the PHP code at the back end. When sorting is toggled at the table, it sends an API call which returns the data in specific order, so each time you click to toggle sorting by a specific value or order, it sends that data through POST, and at the back end there is logic like following for all the columns

```
ORDER BY $colname $direction
```

The problem is that some of the data rendered in the table are not contained in a specific table in DB, but in a json, in a column called 'other'. Is there an easy way, or 1 line query that can modify ORDER BY command to work with a specific element in JSON?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Just stop sending the API request, when the column is not available in the DB tables

Comment: 5.5.58-MariaDB on my vagrant vm

Comment: Then you cannot use the MySQL 5.7 JSON DataType. So now you will have to give us a bigger clue as to what the `other` column looks like on your database

Comment: @RiggsFolly something like this http://prntscr.com/ixy99b Some of these elements will contain strings, and I'd like to sort rows according to them